# button.setEnabled(false) doesn't work in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-button

Ok, may be I doesn't understand something, but I can't disable button in ViewPager view,
Here is a sample ,where i try to disable button:

**ViewPagerAdapter:**

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {

        if(views.size()>position&&views.get(position)!=null)
        {
            currentView=views.get(position);

        }
        else {
            currentView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_cardbase_viewpager, container, false);
            currentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                ....
                Button saveCard = (Button)currentView.findViewById(R.id.save_card_button);
                if(textColor == Color.BLACK){
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        saveCard.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.button_color_black,mActivity.getTheme()));
                    }else{
                        saveCard.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.button_color_black));
                    }
                }else{
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        saveCard.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.button_color_white, mActivity.getTheme()));
                    }else{
                        saveCard.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.button_color_white));
                    }
                }
                if(db.checkIfCardAdded(pagerItems.get(position).getCardID())){
                    Log.e("Card already added",pagerItems.get(position).getCardName());
                    saveCard.setEnabled(false);
                }


            }


            ((ViewPager)container).addView(currentView);
            return currentView;
        }
```

Why disabling doesn't work? How should I correctly disable button? 
"If" code works well. Also I tried to disable button without "if" , but this did no sense.
Can anyone explain me about my problem?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_back_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <Button
               android:id="@+id/save_card_button"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:text="Save"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/card_back_logo"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/white">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/barcode"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                    android:id="@+id/cardCode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/barcode_card_base"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/cardHolder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: why is your `ViewGroup container` is final?

Comment: @MuchOverflow because i need to use it in onClick event in animationListener

Comment: do you fixed it . ? @Ololoking

Comment: oh. cool, does button should be enabled or disabled based on the condition and it applies to all the items in the list ? correct ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan button should be enabled for first, when the viewpager adapter creates for each view of the adapter i check if it exist in DataBase(Sqlite) ,and if yes button should be disabled

Comment: don't you enable it somewhere after?

Comment: @bendaf no, i didn't

Comment: try to set setClickable(false) also

Comment: Could you add `R.id.save_card_button` XML, please? Maybe enabled/clickable attributes got mixed.

Comment: @bendaf i tried to use it, no sense

Comment: @everyman check my question, i add xml layout

Comment: @Ololoking check my answer if it works for u

Answer (score 0):

You need to setEnable(true) in the else part of your code. It will definitely work.

```
if (db.checkIfCardAdded(pagerItems.get(position).getCardID())) {
  Log.e("Card already added", pagerItems.get(position).getCardName());
  saveCard.setEnabled(false);
} else {
  saveCard.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Any issues let me know.

Comment: Code that you provides works as mine, also i find an issue that when i disable button in xml layout it doesn't works too

Comment: don't use disable button in XML, try to control it programatically